# MS SQL Server's STDistance output differs from Google Earth/Maps straight line distance

Tags: google-maps, coordinate-system, sql-server, distance, google-earth

I am testing SQL Server STDistance function in the following way:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;

SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(53.553813 9.99158)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(52.5234051 13.4113)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);
```

These points represent, respectively, Hamburg and Berlin.

The `STDistance` call above returns `394612.166639773` (aprox. 394km). However, on Google Earth/Maps, when I calculate the straight line between the two points above, I get aprox. 254km.

If I understood correctly, both SQL Server `SRID 4326` and Google Earth represent/use the `WGS84` reference system, so I don't know what else could be causing this difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/stdistance-unit-in-sql-server-2008 answer this question?

Comment: I'm not at work, where I can check the GM/GE distance, but an online geodesic calculation program returns 394612.1666 m: http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/Inv_Fwd/inverse2.prl

Comment: @whuber I think in that thread the author had the original data in a different format and had to convert it to the one I'm using. But I'm not entirely sure, I'm new to GIS.

Comment: @mkennedy Weird. I just ran it in that URL you sent and got 256414.3059m as the result.

Comment: This sounds awfully familiar: are you sure you are putting latitude and longitude in the correct order?  (That problem has come up here many, many times.)  According to examples on the [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933834.aspx), longitude goes first.

Comment: Oh, that was it @whuber!! Thanks a lot. I should have thought about that. Sorry for bothering with something this simple.

Comment: Converting to dms for that tool is also a pain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bill Huber gave the right answer in the comments. I delayed the answer by running the NGS inverse tool incorrectly.

It looks like confusion between latitude and longitude order. I did put the coordinates in the wrong order when I used the NGS inverse tool. Stupid of me! If I enter values correctly, the geodesic distance is 256414.3059 m. If I enter the coordinates incorrectly (latitude = 13.4113 rather than longitude = 13.4113), the geodesic distance is 394612.1666 m.

Thus, ST_Distance in SQL Server requires coordinates in longitude, latitude order.

Comment: As I indicated, this isn't the first time exactly this mistake has been reported here and it won't be the last.  The best diagnostic clue I know of (without redoing the calcs) is to compare the incorrect and correct distances (here, in the ratio 254/394 = about 0.64).  When this ratio is approximately the ratio of cosines of the latitudes involved (here, 50 degrees versus 10-13 degrees if the coordinates are switched, about a 0.62:0.98 ratio = 0.64 again), that's a clear sign that either there's a coordinate mixup or the software is using Euclidean calculations on geographic coordinates.

Comment: @mkennedy Can you please take a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413831/sql-server-stintersects-stdistance-and-stcointains-with-lat-lon-points-and-geom), as it refers to a similar question?